# Consider using PDO instead

Tags: mysqli, pdo

I have just converted my whole site to `MySQLi` and optimized the security, but people are now saying **"use PDO instead"**.

Am I messing something? Is `MySQLi` also going to be deprecated in the future? I'm confused.

Comment: Consider the following, [Usability problems of mysqli compared to PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/usab)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Gotcha. So I can continue to use MySQLi?

Comment: @carl MySQLi is in no immediate danger of deprecation, and you shouldn't worry about its future, but it has a frustrating API for prepared statements and eliminates the possibility of switching to a different database.